# Can I pass an object to a WebApi controller using WebClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am playing around with the new webapi.

Is it possible using WebClient to pass an object or do I need to create a query string within the WebClient? this is a basic example of a model I have

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebClient is very basic and only designed to retreive data using a GET so you have to embed everything into the query string. If you need more, like use the content to serialize an object with a POST request, you can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [HttpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/httpclient-is-here.aspx)